# C# SQL stored procedure call values

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to communicate with the database, I am little bit confused about how to pass a value as a parameter(for ex. an itemID) and get back the records that are having this ID.

**Here is my stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_lightItem]
(
    @itemID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT [itemID],
       [itemName],
       [itemLocation],
       [itemChBy]
FROM   [dbo].[Item] 
WHERE itemSystemType='E'  and itemID=@itemID ORDER BY itemID DESC;
END
```

**And this is my c# code so far..**

```
 public string LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
 {
     var acf = new AcFunctions();
     var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_lightItem", ItemID);
 }
```

As you can see in stored procedure, what I want is to get back those 4 elements:

```
[itemID],[itemName],[itemLocation],[itemChBy]
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to get them back/how to call them in c# function.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this approach, I will use **Data Transfer Object** for holding data retrieved from database and **Execute DataReader** for reading.

First of all, you need to create a DTO class, I will call it **LightItemDTO**

```
public class LightItemDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string ChangedBy { get; set; }
        }
```

Note: How to know the type of properties, you can reference this link: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

And now, I will using ADO.NET for execute the stored procedure to get data from database

```
public IEnumerable<LightItemDTO> GetLightItem(string itemText, string sqlConnectionString)
        {
            var results = new List<LightItemDTO>();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_lightItem", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = itemText;
                    con.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        results.Add(new LightItemDTO
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["itemID"]),
                            Name = reader["itemName"].ToString(),
                            Location = reader["itemLocation"].ToString(),
                            ChangedBy = reader["itemChBy"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Using DataReader is the best practice with high performance.
ADO.NET is the manual way to achieve this task, you can use some ORM framework for do it easier, such as: Entity Framework, Dapper.NET ...

Answer (score 3):

i dont have enough repo to comment , can you provide the definition   of

```
AcFunctions();
```

i am sure you it must be returning ConnectionString

try this

```
 public string LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
            {
    var acf = new AcFunctions();
    var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_lightItem", new SqlParameter ("@itemID",ItemID));
}
```

**Edit 1** 
try this

```
  public string LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
    {
            List<string> testList = new List<string>();            

        var acf = new AcFunctions();


        var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(acf.AcConn(), "sp_lightItem", new SqlParameter ("@itemID",ItemID));

     if(newstorevalue.HasRows)
    {





           while(newstorevalue.Read())
           {
               testList.Add(newstorevalue["itemID"].ToString());
               testList.Add(newstorevalue["itemName"].ToString());
               testList.Add(newstorevalue["itemLocation"].ToString());
               testList.Add(newstorevalue["itemChBy"].ToString());
          }

    }

 }
```

Comment: The code seems to be ok so far, my problem is how to get the 4 elements back (itemID,itemName,itemLocation,itemChBy). I do not know(cause I am new on coding) how to store the returned values in C# code.

Comment: what is itemSystemType ?

Comment: the values returned are stored in newstorevalue which will be a DataSet all you need to do is to fetch them from there , if you are not sure how to do that i can edit my answer

Comment: So you are telling me that in newstorevalue I do have the informations I need. How exactly can I extract those values in seperate? Thank you

Comment: do you want to bind it to controls like gridview etc or you want to store the values in an object , please give more details so that i can help you getting what you want to

Comment: There is a whole procedure after getting the values back. My approach is to print them in screen via Angular(I have already create the html, Angular state provider etc). Notice that I am developing in .net mvc As a first step I want to "see" the returned values. (with a breakpoint for ex.)

Answer (score 0):

You could execute stored procedure with parameters in following:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_lightItem", con)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = itemId.Text;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all set the `Commandtype` as `stored procedure` and that procedure will return some data which you will save in `dataset` and then return the data set to where ever you want to populate the data

```
public DataSet LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
 {
     var acf = new AcFunctions();
     return DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(),CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_lightItem",new SqlParameter("@itemID" ItemID);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this ..

```
public string LoadItemNew(int ItemID)
{
     var acf = new AcFunctions();
     List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
     parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@itemID", ItemID));
     DataSet Ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(),CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_lightItem" , parameters.ToArray());
     return "ok";
}
```